# Turn off Cached Exchange mode with a Gmail account Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2016

How can I disable Cached Exchange mode on Outlook with a Gmail account?
Because instead of seeing the "Use Cached Exchange Mode" chekbox while entering account settings in Outlook 2016 like here:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaPRD.png)

Instead I see this:
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4jxW.png)
No checkbox, just a "Compress" button.

Is the Cached Exchange mode changeable for Gmail accounts?

Comment: Gmail account is not an Exchange account, so you cannot using a gmail account in/not in Cached Exchang mode in Outlook desktop client.

Comment: @Aidan: is there any ways to tell Outlook to not save mails locally at all?